# Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia proprietary drivers installation

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, drivers, nvidia

I require some Help and Guidance in installing NVIDIA drivers on my system with a Dual Intel/Nvidia Graphics Processors.

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 and i am aware that the OS is in its late Beta stage however i perform daily Updates. The OS is running fine and smooth so i can not say that i have experienced any problems.

Following the installation method from below I successfully installed the Nvidia Driver without any errors. However upon restarting the system I was presented with a black screen.

Following a solution, I blacklisted the Nouveau Driver and performed another restart where uppon I was presented with the logging screen but in a 4/3 aspect ratio Format. I was unable to continue the log in to the Unity Desktop because the system froze and rendered the Mouse and keyboard inoperable.

Following another solution i then restarted the system in console mode where i proceeded to check the nvidia-xorg file. I noticed the settings looked  odd as `Section "Device"` and `Screen` were missing. I tried recreating the file as per instructions using `nvidia-xconfig` but i received an error "**Unable to load X Server Display Configuration page:**". At that point I gave up and re installed Ubuntu. I repeated this Process Once  more but with no Success. I am currently running Ubuntu without the Nvidia drivers and i disabled the card using this method "**apt-get install --no-install-recommends bumblebee**". However i would like to get the Nvidia Card working.

```
sudo apt-get purge libvdpau-va-gl1
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
```

Hardware:

- Dell Inspiron 15R N5110 laptop
- Intel I5
- Card 1: Intel HD Graphics 3000 ("Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller")
- Nvidia Geforce GT525M ("NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 525M]")

Software:

- X.Org: 1.15.0 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz
- GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.0

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain how you installed the drivers, what you mean by frozen, perhaps include a screenshot and show the output of `inxi -G` (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/inxi/wiki/Installation) for how to install it). Oh, and sorry about removing those two words in my edit, that was done by accident.

Comment: will do, ill get my notes

Answer (score 2):

There seems some issue with optimus dual video systems. You need to open your terminal and enter the commands below:

First remove current Nvidia installation.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Install Kernel header if didn't already

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Then install bumblebee using below commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

For more up-to-date nvidia drivers, you need to add another PPA. As of 12.04, this is still necessary for Nvidia GT 6xxM cards. It may be optional for the GT 4xxM and GT 5xxM series on 12.04. When in doubt, just install it. The command is:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

`sudo apt-get update`

Install Bumblebee using the proprietary nvidia driver:

`sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`

Reboot or re-login

If you have 32-bit applications like Wine, and run 11.10 Oneiric or later, you will need extra libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386
```

Allow yourself to use Bumblebee by adding yourself to the 'bumblebee' group. (replace $USER by your username)

```
sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER
```

Reboot or re-login to apply the group changes If you'd like to run a program on the nvidia card now, use the optirun program:

`optirun firefox &`

Also please look into this thread:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2075423

Comment: if you install primus instead of virtualgl use primusrun

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it's the solution:

1. Open Additional drivers
2. Select the Nvidia binary driver (proprietary, tested)

[image: Something like this]

3. Type the following commands:

   sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
   sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
   sudo apt-get -y update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime

The **big** problem here is that you can't use both Intel HD and Nvidia togather, but separately they work well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For sure next time when i buy laptop ill make sure its compatible with ubuntu in every way. :)