# Ubuntu 14.04 black screen after Nvidia Driver 352

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, reboot

I wanted to make use of my Nvidia graphic card so after a little bit of reading I saw that it is possible to change it in the Additional Drivers. 
It's somewhat similar to here: [Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia proprietary drivers installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120955/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-proprietary-drivers-installation)

Apparently it worked, at least that's what I thought in the beginning.

However, after restart, I get a black screen, although I could hear the Ubuntu login screen sound.

The thing is, I don't know how to fix it, how could I get pass that black screen to change the option to something that works?

Comment: Hi Geo, there are 2 answers related to this on AskUbuntu, either http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433 or http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076 will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the help. Among that bulk of links, I managed to find a solution for my problem. This one was particularly useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver